# Group sortable dynamically added element on $_POST

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I'm totally lacking of thoughts on doing this, here is the image to start with

[image: sample form]

*all box are textbox (editable) 
*all box are draggable and sortable 
*all box are dynamically added

I have a button "Add Group" that generate green textbox and "Add Question" that generate brown box

sample code for textbox

```
<input type="text" name="question[]">
<input type="text" name="group[]">
```

could anyone help me please, if user like the question not to be in group he just place it to top like Q1, if he want the question to be in group he just place it bellow the group textbox.

the draggable and sortable part is already working

what I need to save it to db like this 
 [image]

Comment: i have tried to POST it since its array `$group = ([0]=>"group abc", [1]=>qwe); $question = ([0]=>Q1,[1]=>Q4,[2]=>Q3,[3]=>Q5,[4]=>Q2,[4]=>Q6);` i'm trying to manipulate now this result still working on it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to identify to which group each question contains. For that you can keep a matching indexes for the group and related questions.

for example see the following html

```
<input type="text" name="group[1]">
<input type="text" name="question[1][]">
<input type="text" name="question[1][]">
<input type="text" name="question[1][]">

<input type="text" name="group[2]">
<input type="text" name="question[2][]">
<input type="text" name="question[2][]">
<input type="text" name="question[2][]">
```

This is what i have done to form such elements, where `i` is a global js variable that keeps the index. Each time a group is created the index is incremented.

```
$('#addG').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.divGroup').removeClass('active');
    var div = $('<div>').attr('data-id', i).attr('class', 'divGroup active').html('click me to add questionin this group');
    var g = $('<input>').attr('name', 'group[' + i + ']').attr('class', 'group').attr('placeholder','Enter Group name here');
    div.append(g);
    var ul = $('<ul>').attr('class', 'sortable');
    $(ul).sortable({
      connectWith: ".sortable"
    }).disableSelection();
    var newLi = $('<li><input type="text" placeholder="Question here" class="question" name="question['+ i+  '][]"/></li>').draggable(draggable_opts);
    ul.append(newLi);
    div.append(ul);
    $('#form').append(div);
    i++; // global index incremented
});
```

I think making the group textbox draggable is a bad idea, so i have only made the questions sortable. Now the problem is if a question is dragged from one group to another the questions index has to change. We can achieve that with the following code:

```
$( "#form" ).on( "sortstop",'.sortable', function( event, ui ) { 
       var divId = $(ui.item).closest('div.divGroup').attr('data-id');
       $(ui.item).attr('name','question['+divId+'][]'); 
} );
```

What i do here is rename the name attribute of the textbox to match the group index. Group index is stored in a div's custom attribute names `data-id`, you can see that in code.

Now from server, even if the index of the group are not consecutive you can fetch the group and questions as follows:

```
<?php
  $groups = $_POST['group'];
  $question = $_POST['question'];
  foreach($groups as $key=>$val){
    echo "Questions for Group : $val are ";
    print_r($questions[$key]); 
  }
?>
```

You can find the working example of script [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6Y6wg/1/)

Comment: multidimentional array, i forgot about that +1

Answer (score 0):

You need two mysql tables

- Groups
  ID | Group-name
- Questions
  ID | GroupID | Question

And to make it sortable. The easiest is a list per group, and a button "Add question" below every group.

Comment: the frontend part draggable and sortable is done, I need some thoughts on my php to save it like in the image, question updated sir. thanks thanks

Answer (score 0):

since this item is sortable

```
<input type="text" name="question[]">
<input type="text" name="group[]">
```

I need to know who comes first, so what I did is I named them

```
<input type="text" name="fields[][0]"><!--0 is for group-->
<input type="text" name="fields[][1]"><!--1 is for question-->
```

by doing this, we know who comes first and PHP do the conditionals

so here's my PHP and sample $_POST array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array([1] => Q1)
    [1] => Array([0] => group abc)
    [2] => Array([1] => Q4)
    [3] => Array([1] => Q3)
    [4] => Array([1] => Q4)
    [5] => Array([0] => Group qwe)
    [6] => Array([1] => Q2)
    [7] => Array([1] => Q6)
)
```

.

```
$questionType = $this->input->post('fields');
    $group = "";
for($i = 0; $i < count($questionType); $i++){
    if(isset($questionType[$i][0])){ 
        $group  = $questionType[$i][0];
    }
    if(isset($questionType[$i][1])){
        $this->model->insertQuestion($group,$questionType[$i][1]); //save to db
    }
}
```